# How to send raw bytes using Hyperterminal?

Tags: windows-xp, hyperterminal

For example, I'd like to send 0xAA, 0x00 etc, not some character or string, through Hyperterminal. Is it possible? How? I'm using Windows XP Professional SP2.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://realterm.sourceforge.net/

From the site:

> Realterm is a terminal program
>   specially designed for capturing,
>   controlling and debugging binary and
>   other difficult data streams. It is
>   far better for debugging comms than
>   Hyperterminal. It has no support for
>   dialing modems, BBS etc - that is what
>   hyperterminal does.

Perhaps this helps?

Comment: Yes it helps. Though I was looking for a way to send data through hyperterminal, not any alternative.

Answer (score 0):

Sending raw bytes is possible using the ALT+NUMPAD entry method. So for Donotalo's 0xAA example, he would type ALT+0170. However, due to a deficiency of the ALT+NUMPAD entry method, sending 0x00 using ALT+0 does not work.

The workaround for sending 0x00 is to transfer an ASCII text file that contains a single zero byte.